# How to make an image sprite on Android (not anim 2d)?

Tags: android, sprite

I want to program a sprite in Android in order to avoid having many image files . I don't wanna use it like an anim , but for having drawables with an unique real image file (for example *.png ) .

Is there a way to do that?

Thanks for all.

Comment: You are trying to say that you want to show different images animation using single image like TiledTextureRegion in AndEngine?

Comment: I'm trying to say that what i want is to use an only image file for multple drawables in distinct imagebuttons or another things . Like google does in his web for not having many files and image request.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the detailed tutorial and the source code over here

http://www.edu4java.com/en/androidgame/androidgame5.html

http://obviam.net/index.php/sprite-animation-with-android/

All the best!!!